# Image sharing in iOS

Tags: ios, image, share

In iOS I noticed you can select a photo in your Photo app and then share it using other apps (eg. Whatsapp, Telegram, etc.). I would like to implement the same functionality in my app, but I don't know where to start. Can you help me? The things I don't understand are:

1. how my app can be listed between the apps that can share images;
2. how my app "knows" what to do when a user selects an image;

I know this is basic, maybe trivial, but I searched a little maybe using the wrong keywords, I dunno.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Those are two very broad questions. I suggest you start by reading the [Apple documentation about App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html)

Comment: Specifically, Share Extensions are described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1)

Comment: As for what your app should do with the content it receives, that's really up to you!

Comment: @jcaron: this is ok, my question (badly written) was about an eventual method automatically invoked or something like that   ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reference on accessing images iOS:

- [Open gallery with photos and videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165761/open-gallery-with-videos-and-photos-in-ios)

Here are some references on sharing images with iOS:

- [Sharing and Actions](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/sharing-and-actions/)
- [App Extension Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1)

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the simple question

Comment: No problem! I would suggest giving a little more detail next time like what language you are using and focusing on getting the answer to one of those questions.